# Spring Cloud Stream Kafka retries 10 times the maxAttempts

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I've been trying to implement retry logic for Spring cloud stream kafka such that if an exception is throw when producing an event to the topic `sample-topic`, It retries two more time.
I added in the following configuration to the application.properties file

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.processSampleEvent.destination=sample-topic
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.processSampleEvent.content-type=application/json
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.processSampleEvent.consumer.maxAttempts=2
```

I've written the lister code in way that it simply logs the received message and throws a NullPointerException so that I can test out the retry.

```java
@StreamListener(ListenerBind.SAMPLE_CHANNEL)
  public void processSampleEvent(String productEventDto) {
    System.out.println("Entering listener: " + productEventDto);
    throw new NullPointerException();
}
```

But when testing out by producing an event to the `sample-topic`, I see that in the logs the event has been retries 20 times but I've specified in the properties to try only two time and also a weird thing happens when I change to it 3 times, It retries 30 times.
I'm pretty new to Spring cloud streams and any help on this would be really helpful.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

The default error handler in the listener container is now a `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` with 10 delivery attempts.

You can either disable the retries in the binder, and configure a `STCEH` with the retry semantics you want, or use retries in the binder and replace the default error handler with a simple `LoggingErrorHandler`.

To configure the container's error handler, add a `ListenerContainerCustomizer<AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory>` `@Bean`.

Comment: I observed that the behavior of retrying 10 times of `maxAttempts` does not apply when `enableDlq=true`. Could you shed some light of the reason behind?

Comment: Because the error is "recovered" by sending the record to the dead letter topic and no exception is thrown to the container, so its error handler is not invoked.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Nonetheless, isn't this Kafka binder's retry-10-times behavior contradicting with SCSt `maxAttempts` definition? Is there any plan to make them consistent?

Comment: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/1135

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem.
My working solution was to create a ListenerContainerCustomizer Bean, give it desired number of max attempts, and set consumer binding maxAttempts: 1

```
@Bean
public ListenerContainerCustomizer<AbstractMessageListenerContainer<?,?>> listenerContainerCustomizer(){
    return (container, dest, group) ->
          container.setErrorHandler(containerAwareErrorHandler());
}
public SeekToCurrentErrorHandler containerAwareErrorHandler(){
    return new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(new FixedBackOff(0, maxAttempts-1);
}
```